# Is it possible to set breakpoints in razor views with servicestack?

Tags: razor, servicestack

I am trying out the new razor view stuff in service stack, and I have this view:

```
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<ServiceStackRazorCrud.Api.UserPageResourceResponse>
@{
    var m = Model;  // <-- I have a breakpoint in this line.
    var req = Request; 
    var res = Response;
}
```

When I set a breakpoints and run the application (console application) I can see that the view is compiled but the debugger does not break when I request the view in the browser. I assume that this is because the views are compiled dynamically at application start or something like that. Is it possible somehow to get the breakpoints to work?

Comment: Would be really good to get some feedback on this question. It seem to be a bit of a black art at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it's not possible to debug views this way (currently using 3.9.43, later version I believe has better diagnostics for compilation errors).

Try and keep view code simple, restricted to simple loops/rendering and using extension methods on DTO's for any complex logic/processing, which do allow debugging. You might also consider utilizing [logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging), or a simple Debug extension method:

```
using ServiceStack.Html;
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDebug(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
    #if DEBUG
        return true;
    #else
        return false;
    #endif
    }
}

@using ServiceStack.Text
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<ServiceStackRazorCrud.Api.UserPageResourceResponse>
@{
    var m = Model;  
}

@if (this.Html.IsDebug())
{
    <div class="debug">@(this.Model == null ? "m == null" : Model.Dump())</div>
}
```